# Is there (and what if there is) a difference in saying nozzle and nuzzle?

Tags: pronunciation

To my *Russian* ear, it appears that both nozzle and nuzzle sound the same. Is it true? If no, what is the difference?

Comment: You can tell from context even in dialects where the pronunciation is not different  Put the nozzle on the hose.  The dog wanted to nuzzle the bag of groceries.

Comment: "sound the same" to ***who**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers to a non-native speaker unlike you?

Comment: @468: I very much doubt that ***all*** non-native speakers find it difficult to distinguish what to me are significantly different vowel sounds, though I'm prepared to concede that even I as a native BrE speaker (who also listens to a *lot* of AmE accents) wouldn't be likely to notice if someone managed to present me with a soundtrack where an AmE speaker used both words in the same utterance, but they were then cunningly digitally transposed. Whatever - I suggest it might be easier to answer your question meaningfully if you told us ***what*** your native language is.

Comment: @FumbleFingers my native language is russian

Comment: Have you checked both AmE ***and*** BrE versions of both words (on [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/nuzzle), for example? As it happens, I can easily hear a big difference between the AmE versions there, but I'm sure there are other AmE accents where it would be much less obvious (or indistinguishable) to me. In short, do you recognise a phonetic distinction in *any* native Anglophone accent?

Comment: i can hear the difference when both words are used within the same sentence, i can tell american accent from british, i know that in written notation the sounds are supposed to be different, my problem is that when either word is used alone i can only rely on the context, my second problem is that when it comes to saying it i will most definitely say it wrong, because i can't see the clear difference in the first place

Comment: You can't hear nuzzle as different from nozzle because Russian does not have the u vowel sound. In my experience Russians also cannot hear the difference between man and men. Going the other way, Americans can't hear the difference between бить and быть.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to explain what you already know about the pronunciation of these two words and what sources you’ve checked, we should be able to take your question off hold. Understanding what you already know helps us write better answers.

Comment: @David42 interestingly there is `ы` sound in `nimble` somewhere between `b` and `l` in russian it would have been written as `нимбыл`

Answer (score 2):

No, they do not sound the same in American English.  *Nozzle* is pronounced näzəl (or nɒzəl in [IPA](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:International_Phonetic_Alphabet)) and *nuzzle* is pronounced nəzəl.  To put it informally, [*n**o**zzle* has an "aah" sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_back_rounded_vowel) and [*n**u**zzle* has an "uhh" sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_central_vowel).

[You can listen to the difference between the two words here](https://www.naturalreaders.com/online?s=V254l6equfv4g8gsosso0gwo8so.pdf&t=NaturalReader%20Document); it is a computer-generated voice but the pronunciation is pretty good.

Comment: it appears that only when 2 words are said in the same sentence can you hear it

Comment: @468: A native speaker  of a dialect where the words have different main vowels will hear the difference even when only one of the words is spoken.  Do you hear the difference when someone is punched in the solar plexus and when someone sinks back into a warm bath?

Comment: @468 - I think I could hear the difference even if the words are said in isolation, but I agree that it is easier to hear the difference if the words are in the same sentence.  If your language does not contain both sounds, or if it does contain both sounds but they do not make a semantic difference (that is, a difference in meaning), it will be hard for you to hear the phonemic difference (that is, the difference in sound).

Comment: I'm not going to go looking for a "natural" example of both words being used in the same utterance from one of those AmE accents where *my internal recollection* is they sound the same (or at least, extremely similar). It does seem unlikely there would be a dialect where the speaker himself considered the words homophonous (stranger things have certainly happened though, so never say never!). But approximately, I assume I could *train* myself to recognise unfamiliar disambiguating elements in [almost?] all cases - I just can't see why I might want to, since ***context*** is always there.

Answer (score 1):

They could sound quite similar when spoken in many Northern-British (e.g. Geordie) accents, especially for a non-native ear. (However many other northern words could be quite difficult to distinguish by the rest of the world, if I can say that without offending too many of our northern countrymen!).

But the context would usually indicate which word was intended, as the two words have very different meanings.